# Заполнение CSV с помощью PHP

Tags: php, csv

Есть такой код:

```
fwrite($csv, b"\xEF\xBB\xBF" ) ;
fputcsv($csv, array('Имя файла', 'Название', 'Автор', 'Материал', 'Размеры', 'Дата создания', 'Музей', 'Страна, город', 'Примечание'));
foreach ($_POST as list($filename, $name, $author, $material, $scale, $date, $museum, $city, $notation)) {
  fputcsv($csv, [$filename, $name, $author, $material, $scale, $date, $museum, $city, $notation]);
}
```

Но столбцы заполняются не по вертикали, а все значения просто идут друг за другом - вначале все элементы $filename, затем - $name... и так далее. Почему?

И как корректно перебрать этот массив с внутренними массивами для заполнения CSV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте разберемся с циклом

```
foreach ($_POST as list($filename, $name, $author, $material, $scale, $date, $museum, $city, $notation)) {
    // ...
}
```

Это значит что вы перебираете элементы массива `$_POST`, ожидая, что каждый из элементов - тоже массив и значения уже этого массива вы раскладываете по переменным `$filename, $name...`. Однако, мне хрустальный шар подсказывает что ваш $_POST - выглядит примерно так:

```
array(
    'filename' => array('file1', 'file2', /* ... */),
    'name'     => array('name1', 'name2', /* ... */),
    // ...
)
```

Соответственно вы сначала в `list($filename, $name, $author...)` подставляете значения из `$_POST['filename']` (в лучшем случае), потом из `$_POST['name']`, и т. д.

Выведите массив `$_POST` функцией `print_r()` и подумайте как *нужно* написать

**Дополнено**

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
$fields = array(
    'filename',
    'name',
    'author',
    'material',
    'scale',
    'date',
    'museum',
    'city',
    'notation'
);
for ($rowIndex = 0; ; $rowIndex += 1) {
    $row = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (isset($_POST[$field][$rowIndex])) {
            $row[] = $_POST[$field][$rowIndex];
        } else {
            break 2;
        }
    }
    fputcsv($csv, $row);
}
```

Comment: Ваш хрустальный шар прав, но я не понимаю, как переписать запрос - я хотел избавиться от двух foreach, поэтому и дописал list.

Comment: Потому что это ведь все равно массив массивов, пусть внутренние и заключены в переменные.

Comment: Чем вам второй цикл не угодил? В PHP я не нашел красивых решений по "транспонированию" массивов (когда меняются местами индексы первого и второго порядков)

Comment: В итоге так сделал: foreach ($_POST['link'] as $k=>$link) {
 fputcsv($csv, array($_POST['filename'][$k], $_POST['name'][$k], $_POST['author'][$k], $_POST['material'][$k], $_POST['scale'][$k], $_POST['date'][$k], $_POST['museum'][$k], $_POST['city'][$k], $_POST['notation'][$k]));
} - там все равно одинаковое количество элементов.

Comment: С двумя foreach я все равно не понял, как можно было корректно заполнить CSV. Поможете? Как можно было бы?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov обновил ответ

Comment: а так точно корректно?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov А какие некорректности вы предполагаете?

Comment: Нет, все в порядке, спасибо.